# Как найти путь до листа в дереве решений?

Tags: python

В наличии имеется бинарное дерево представленное следующим видом:
Пример

```
left_children =  [1, 3, 5, 7, -1, 9, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] # левые потомки
right_children = [2, 4, 6, 8, -1, 10, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] # правые потомки
```

Индекс массивов соответствует номеру вершины дерева.-1 в массиве означает, что у вершины по этому индексу нету детей.
Пытаюсь получить словарь, где ключом является индекс вершины (листа), а значением массив целых чисел указывающих путь до этого листа. Для массивов выше нужно получить:

```
result = {
    4: [1, 0], # для того, чтобы попасть в узел 4 нужно пройти от узла 0 к узлу 1, а потом к узлу 4
    7: [3, 1, 0],
    8: [3, 1, 0],
    9: [5, 2, 0],
    10: [5, 2, 0],
    11:[6, 2, 0],
    12: [6, 2, 0]
}
```

[image: Само дерево решений]
Как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358045/how-can-i-implement-a-tree-in-python

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что предлагается создать класс Node и Tree. А потом бэкрефом искать путь?

Comment: Нужно получить пути для всех вершин или только для определённых, как в вашем примере -  `[4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`?

Comment: Для всех. Я просто заранее индексы всех висящих вершин вывел в отдельный список.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не создавать структуру дерева:

```
left_children =  [1, 3, 5, 7, -1, 9, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] # левые потомки
right_children = [2, 4, 6, 8, -1, 10, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] # правые потомки
parents = [-1]*len(left_children)
for i in range(len(left_children)):
    if left_children[i] > 0:
        parents[left_children[i]] = i
    if right_children[i] > 0:
        parents[right_children[i]] = i

dic = {}
for i in range(len(left_children)):
    if left_children[i] > 0:
        p = []
        parent = i
        while parent >=0:
           p.append(parent)
           parent = parents[parent]
        dic[left_children[i]] = p
    if right_children[i] > 0:
        p = []
        parent = i
        while parent >=0:
           p.append(parent)
           parent = parents[parent]
        dic[right_children[i]] = p
print(dic)


{1: [0], 2: [0], 3: [1, 0], 4: [1, 0], 5: [2, 0], 6: [2, 0], 
 7: [3, 1, 0], 8: [3, 1, 0], 9: [5, 2, 0], 10: [5, 2, 0], 
 11: [6, 2, 0], 12: [6, 2, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Бинарное дерево можно представить как массив, знаю видео на английском [Heap - Heap Sort - Heapify - Priority Queues](https://youtu.be/HqPJF2L5h9U), в начале которого есть хорошее объяснение.

В вашем случае, левые и правые узлы лежат в отдельных списках, если их соединить попеременно и добавить `0` в качестве корня, получим следующий список:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -1, -1, 9, 10, 11, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

который в тоже время будет являться вытянутым в линию бинарным деревом. Предок узла `x` этого дерева находится по формуле:

```
x_parent_index = (x_index - 1) // 2
```

**Пример:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание, что предок находится по индексу узла, а не по значению. А в результат пишем значения узлов - не индексы.

- узел со значением **12** имеет индекс **14**. Ищем его предка.
- предок узла с индексом **14** = `(14 - 1) // 2` = **6**, индекс и значение совпадают.
- предок узла с индексом **6** = `(6 - 1) // 2` = **2**, индекс и значение совпадают.
- предок узла с индексом **2** = `(2 - 1) // 2` = **0**, индекс и значение совпадают.

Таким образом путь от узла со значением **12** (индекс которого **14**) до корня - `6, 2, 0`.

**Решение**

```
left_children =  [1, 3, 5, 7, -1, 9, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] # левые потомки
right_children = [2, 4, 6, 8, -1, 10, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] # правые потомки

bin_tree_as_array = [0]

for childs in zip(left_children, right_children):
    bin_tree_as_array.extend(childs)

result = {}

for node_idx, node_value in enumerate(bin_tree_as_array):
    # Если значение ячейки == -1, значит этого узла нет,
    # соответственно и пути к нему нет
    if node_value == -1:
        continue

    result[node_value] = []
    parent_idx = node_idx
    while parent_idx > 0:
        parent_idx = (parent_idx - 1) // 2
        result[node_value].append(bin_tree_as_array[parent_idx])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

**Output**

```
{0: [],
 1: [0],
 2: [0],
 3: [1, 0],
 4: [1, 0],
 5: [2, 0],
 6: [2, 0],
 7: [3, 1, 0],
 8: [3, 1, 0],
 9: [5, 2, 0],
 10: [5, 2, 0],
 11: [6, 2, 0],
 12: [6, 2, 0]}
```